# Redis (error) NOAUTH Authentication required

Tags: security, authentication, redis

I get the error:

```
(error) NOAUTH Authentication required.
```

When in `redis-cli` and trying to display the `KEYS *`. I've only set a `requirepass` not an `auth` afaiac. I'm in the `redis.conf` but do not know what to do.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Setting the `requirepass` [configuration](https://redis.io/topics/config) directive causes the server to require password authentication with the `AUTH` command before sending other commands. The redis.conf file states that clearly:

> Require clients to issue AUTH  before processing any other
>   commands.  This might be useful in environments in which you do not trust
>   others with access to the host running redis-server.

Comment: so, what are the exact steps to fix the problem?

Comment: @Serge Uh... you comment the requirepass part in the redis.conf file?

Comment: This answer explains why, but no steps to fix OP's question.

Answer (score 64):

```
1. redis-cli
2. auth yourpassword
3. shutdown
4. sudo service redis_6379 start
```

Comment: Simple, concise, and to the point!

Comment: This is the true answer.

Answer (score 18):

first run

```
redis-cli
```

then after the prompt run

```
127.0.0.1:6379> AUTH your_password
```

if all ok you get the `OK`

Answer (score 8):

1. Make sure you have redis-cli installed.
2. Just use following command.

   > redis-cli -h host.domain.com -p port -a yourpassword

Answer (score 3):

comment requirepass (line 480 mostly) in redis.conf file if uncommented.

Comment: Usually have a password for security, probably best to provide a solution than enables the ability to put in the password

Answer (score 1):

specific your redis password in the `redis-cli` command line
eg:

```shell
redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 -a "$your_password"
```

check your `$your_password`.

It's recommend to add double quote to the password on the command line.

Comment: The flag is incorrect here it should `-a` or `--pass` for the password.

Comment: @DannyG thanks. I‘ve corrected my typo

Answer (score 0):

NOAUTH requires to authenticate via AUTH method before executing any get/set/etc. call, in predis that can be done via the auth() method, for example:

```
    $predisClient->auth('username', 'password');
```